# How can I see debug logs in Create React App in production?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, create-react-app

I need to keep the logs on the console in production, how could I disable the removal of these logs in the CRA?
Or would you know how to start me a tool for that that displays the logs in production?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I have a chat and I want to log the channel id on every message sent.

Comment: You can do that in the back-end and easily save the log file.